# Angular2- Template driven form validation for input field in child component

Tags: forms, validation, angular

I was struggling with adding `template driven form validation` in my angular2 app.

i have a forked the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/phhe74kAUmNZgNSmcsvm?p=preview

i failed to achieve the form validation for my `custom component` alone and other html components are working fine.

In the plunker, if you start typing `name` and `street` it will updated in both `form` and and my `model object` as well. but the when you start typing `postcode` it will update only in my `model object` and `not with form`.

I wanted the `form` to be `invalid` if i make `postcode` filed to empty.

Is  i missed something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, your form doesn't recognize your child components' input field as a form field, you need to change your child tag a bit... to have the `name` attribute and `ngModel` to bind this child component to the form. Also include `required` here.

Lastly, you need to add `ngDefaultControl` to have two-way binding for the form field. So your child tag should look like this in your parent:

```
<my-input name="postcode" ngModel ngDefaultControl required [(value)]="user.address.postcode"></my-input>
```

Here is your forked

### [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/aaUXl41vvoHUVkDWkd3B?p=preview)